# How can the title be updated in an existing ppt slide using python

Tags: python, python-pptx

I have an title name to update which is dynamic I will be passing that through uipath, but how can the title be updated to an existing ppt

Comment: wht have you tried so far ?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

I would expect the following to work:

```
slide.title.text = "New Title Text"
```